# Examples of Intervals

Tags: real-analysis

*Claim.* Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers. If $a\geq b$  then $(a,b), [a,b)$ and $(a,b]$ are empty set.

My is question is that why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the definitions:
$$(a,b)=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid a<x<b\}$$
With the definitions for $[a,b)$ and $(a,b]$ replacing $<$ by $\leq$ where needed.

So if $a\geq b$, there are no numbers which are *strictly* larger than $a$ **and** *strictly* smaller than $b$. Therefore, the set is empty. The same goes for $[a,b)$ and $(a,b]$.

Note that if $a>b$, then the same holds for $[a,b]$. But if $a=b$, then $[a,b]=\{a\}=\{b\}$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition $(a,b)$ is the set of real numbers $x$ such that $a<x<b$. If $a\ge b$, there are no such real numbers: if $a\ge b$ and $a<x$, then $x>b$, so $x\not<b$. Similarly, $[a,b)$ is the set of real numbers $x$ such that $a\le x<b$, and if $a\ge b$, there are no such real numbers: if $a\ge b$ and $a\le x$, then $x\ge b$, so $x\not<b$. Finally, $(a,b]$ is the set of real numbers $x$ such that $a<x\le b$, and there are no such real numbers: if $a\ge b$ and $a<x$, then $x>b$, so $x\not\le b$. Thus, each of these intervals is empty.

Comment: Too slow, Brian, too slow. :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Out of curiosity, do you remember what the difference was?

Comment: By hovering over the "answered ... ago" you can see the exact time stamp. It says 38 seconds. :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Ah, I didn’t know that about hovering over the *answered* line; thanks!

Comment: One of the first rules of the internet. Hover over anything. You can never know when something contains some useful information. :-)